# Angular Node server returns You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using angular 9 + universal. No errors while i run `ng serve` , then I build the app with `npm run build:ssr` and try to run with node : node dist/app/server/main.js and get the following error in terminal :

> Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000 TypeError: You
>   provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an
>   Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
>       at subscribeTo (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:2547459)
>       at subscribeToResult (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:2775326)
>       at CatchSubscriber.error (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1997435)
>       at Observable_Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1952954)
>       at Observable_Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1952574)
>       at CatchOperator.call (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1996823)
>       at Observable_Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1952428)
>       at _task (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1751796)
>       at Observable_Observable.Observable.a.observer [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1752141)
>       at Observable_Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\andri\OneDrive\Desktop\devfox\autorent\ng-videocms\dist\autorent\server\main.js:1:1952792)

As I've explored, my app does 2 api calls on start :

**app.component.ts  :**

```
ngOnInit(){
get1();
get2();
}

  get1() {
    const loc = this.locationService.getPickupLocations().subscribe((data: Location[]) => {
      this.pickupLocations = data;
      this.formGroup.get(LocationFields.pickup).setValue(data[0].getId());
      this.pickupLocationsList = this.pickupLocations.map((data): ISelectOption => {
        return {
          label: data.getName(),
          value: data.getId(),
        };
      });
    },
    (error)=> {
      console.log(error)
    },
    () => {
      this.subs.add(loc);
      this.pickupDateChange(this.formGroup.get(this.LocationFields.pickupDate).value);
    });
  }


  get2() {
    const drop = this.locationService.getDropOffLocations().subscribe((data: Location[]) => {
      this.dropoffLocations = data;
      this.formGroup.get(LocationFields.dropoff).setValue(data[1].getId());
      this.dropoffLocationsList = this.dropoffLocations.map((data): ISelectOption => {
        return {
          label: data.getName(),
          value: data.getId(),
        };
      });
    },(error)=> {
      console.log(error)
    },
    () => {
      this.subs.add(drop);
    });
  }
```

LocationService.ts :

```
  static locationsEndpoint = 'public/locations/rental';
  getPickupLocations(): Observable<Location[]> {
    const reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'No-Auth': 'True' });
    return this.http.get(`${LocationsService.locationsEndpoint}/pickup`, { headers: reqHeader }).pipe(
     map((data: ILocationResponse) => this.hydrateCollectionData(data, LocationsHydrator))
    );
  }

  getDropOffLocations(): Observable<Location[]> {
    const reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'No-Auth': 'True' });
    return this.http.get(`${LocationsService.locationsEndpoint}/dropoff`, { headers: reqHeader }).pipe(
     map((data: ILocationResponse) => this.hydrateCollectionData(data, LocationsHydrator))
    );
  }
```

And Interceptors :

```
 private static BASE_URL = environment.apiUrl;

  readonly HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = 'Authorization';
  readonly HEADER_ACCEPT = 'Accept';
  readonly HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE = 'Content-Type';
  readonly ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = 'Accept-Language';

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private localeService: LocaleService
  ) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.headers.get('skip')) {
          return next.handle(req);
    }
    if (req.url.startsWith('./assets')) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
    req = req.clone({
      url: this._prefixUrl(req.url)
    });

    req = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set(this.HEADER_ACCEPT, 'application/json')
    });

    req = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set(this.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, 'application/json')
    });

    req = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set(this.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, this.localeService.getLocale())
    });

    // Set token if exists
    const token = this.authService.getToken();

    if (token) {
      req = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.set(this.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, `Bearer ${token}`)
      });
    }

    return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((httpErrorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if(httpErrorResponse.error !== undefined){
          const customError: ApiErrors = {
            name: httpErrorResponse.error.name,
            message: httpErrorResponse.error.message,
            errors: httpErrorResponse.error.errors
          };
          return throwError(customError);
        }
      })
    );
  }

  private _prefixUrl(path: string): string {
    if (path.indexOf('/') === 0) {
      path = path.substr(1, path.length - 1);
    }

    return `${Interceptor.BASE_URL}/${path}`;
  }
```

I tried without these calls , tried to comment one of them.

When i disable those calls (comment them) , app works fine.

When i call them later, after i commented them, (onclick), app works fine.

**When i disable interceptors , it works (SO the problem is in them, what to change ?? )**

**How to fix it ? And why it is happening ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace seems to suggest the problem is related to `CatchOperator`.

I see only one place where `catchError` operator is used in your code

```
return next.handle(req).pipe(
      catchError((httpErrorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if(httpErrorResponse.error !== undefined){
          const customError: ApiErrors = {
            name: httpErrorResponse.error.name,
            message: httpErrorResponse.error.message,
            errors: httpErrorResponse.error.errors
          };
          return throwError(customError);
        }
      })
    );
```

In your code you seem to assume that the function passed to `catchError` will receive always an instance of `HttpErrorResponse` which is not the case. `catchError` will be used for any error and so the function passed to it can receive any type of error.

What happens if `httpErrorResponse.error` **is null** but you still have an error in the upstream Observables somewhere? According to the code above you do not return anything, so this may be the reason why the log says `You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected`.

Rather than not doing anything, you can throw an error, so that you should get the details of the error causing the fact that you enter `catchError` operator, so something like this

```
  catchError(err => {
    if(error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && httpErrorResponse.error !== undefined){
      const customError: ApiErrors = {
        name: httpErrorResponse.error.name,
        message: httpErrorResponse.error.message,
        errors: httpErrorResponse.error.errors
      };
      return throwError(customError);
    } else {
      throw err
    }
  })
);
```